# What is url encoding %2526?

Tags: html, encoding, urlencode

Why is `%2526` used instead of `%26` to encode an `&`?

Im invoking a URL to an external site and when I encode the `&` as `%2526` the parameters are passed correctly but when I just use `%26` they are not.

Comment: That depends on how the external site does the decoding. `encodeURIComponent("&")` gives me `"%26"`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you url-encode an ampersand you get `%26`. If you url-encode `%26` you get `%2526`. Thus, it is url-encoded twice.

Answer (score 8):

`%25` is the percent character, so `%2526` URLDecoded results in

```
%26
```

which URLDecoded results in

```
&
```

For some reason, the call you make seems to require doubly percent encoded input. Without knowing more about what you're doing, it's impossible to know why, but I guess all is in order.

Comment: Just wondering - do you carry these codes in your head or did you run it throug a decoder? :)

Comment: @Czechnology I ran them through a decoder. :) I couldn't memorize stuff like this to save my life!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it gets decoded twice in the process, first from `%2526` to `%26` and then from `%26` to `&`.
You shouldn't dwell too long on the why; if this works, just use it like this.

Comment: "shouldn't dwell too long on the why; if this works, just use it like this" +1

Answer (score 1):

If the URL is used in return URL or value of another query string, the Reserved and Excluded characters should be doubled encoded. & is single-encoded as %26  and double-encoded as  %2526.

Answer (score 0):

`&` is indeed encoded as `%26`.

You can test it creating an HTML file, opening it in a browser, inputing symbols you need to test and looking at the resulting URL in browser:

```
<form>
<input type='text' name='qwe'>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```