# Using Apache URIBuilder '&' symbol in the query parameter gets encoded twice

Tags: java, http, encoding, uri

I am trying to hit a webservice URL with a query parameter as foo & bar with the URL as encoded. To achieve encoding, I am using Apache URIBuilder. The code is as follows:

```
URIBuilder ub = new URIBuilder("http://example.com/query").setParameter("q", "foo & bar");
            URI uri = ub.build();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
            System.out.println(httpget.getURI());
```

I get the following as output: http://example.com/query?q=+foo+%2526+bar

I am new to this JAR file and have 2 questions:

1. Why is the space in the query param replaced with a '+' sign and not with %20 special character.
2. Why is the '&' symbol in the query param getting encoded twice and how to avoid it.

Comment: for you second question take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292865/what-is-url-encoding-2526. and '+' is valid replacement for space character more info here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-or-20).

Comment: Thanks Michal. Sorry for the delay in response.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why is the space in the query param replaced with a '+' sign and not with %20 special character.

In URI encoding, plus sign and %20 are interchangeable. However, another encoding may be used in different environment. For example when you are uploading using `multipart/form-data`, it will use different encoding. Thus you can't use neither %20 nor +.

> 2. Why is the '&' symbol in the query param getting encoded twice and how to avoid it.

It is not encoded twice, but it is URI encoded.

When you put `query=A&B`, you are sending two parameters:

- `query` with value `A`
- `B` with no value

This way, you can't send the actual `&`. To send `&` as a parameter, you must encode the parameter. If you send `query=+foo+%2526+bar`, you are sending only 1 parameter:

- `query` with value `foo & bar`

To send `q=foo&bar`, you need to write this code:

```
URIBuilder ub = new URIBuilder("http://example.com/query");
ub.setParameter("q", "foo");
ub.setParameter("bar", "");
URI uri = ub.build();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
System.out.println(httpget.getURI());
```